# AWS list of container_definitions using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to deploy an aws_ecs_task_definition with multiple container_defintions in Terraform. I have a variable like this, which I use also for other resources creation:

```
variable "entity_map" {
  type = map(object({
    name = string,
    port = number,
    image = string,
    type = string,
    ec2_enabled = bool
    ...
  }))
  default = {
    "entity1" = {
      name = "e1",
      port = 1651, 
      image = "link_to_image1"
      type = "B",
      ec2_enabled = true,
      ...
    },
    "entity2" = {
      name = "e2",
      port = 1655,
      image = "link_to_image2",
      type = "S", 
      ec2_enabled = true,
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is iterate through each object (entity1, entity2, ...) and create as many container_definition inside the task definitions.

What I tried to do is to use dynamic block with the for_each approach but this gives me errors.
For example

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "example" {
  family                   = "example-task"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]

  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn

  dynamic "container_definitions" {
    for_each = var.entity_map
    content {
      name  = each.value.name
      image = each.value.image
      portMappings {
        containerPort = each.value.port
        hostPort      = each.value.port
      }
    }
  }
...
```

The error is:

> │  210:   dynamic "container_definitions" {
> │
> │ Blocks of type "container_definitions" are not expected here.

Comment: I don't think you can use `dynamic` since it's a required argument, and you can have 0 or more values in your variable.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Do you know how can I achieve it without using dynamic? Also container_definitions should be a json encoded variable which contains a list of container definition. It's a bit tricky but there should be a way I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- `container_definitions` is a parameter, and not a block.
- The value of `container_definitions` should be a JSON format string.
- The variable type of `var.entity_map` is a `map(object(...))`, but the resource expects `list(object(...))`.
- The object type is not in the expected structure for the resource/API inputs.

Fixing all of these issues results in:

```
variable "entity_map" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string,
    portMappings = list(object{
      containerPort = number
      hostPort      = number
    })
    port = number,
    image = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name = "e1",
      portMappings = [{
        containerPort = 1651
        hostPort      = 1651
      }]
      image = "link_to_image1"
    },
    {
      name = "e2",
      portMappings = [{
        containerPort = 1655
        hostPort      = 1655
      }]
      image = "link_to_image2"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "example" {
  family                   = "example-task"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]

  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn

  container_definitions = jsonencode(var.entity_map)
  ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the entity_map variable is used also for other resources (for examples ec2s) and each object of the map contains also other properties that are used in other resources, so I cannot change it like that. I will edit my question with this detail.

Comment: @LeoL In that situation then you cannot use a variable input of that type for the parameter value in the resource. You would need to separate the variable into two, or some other similar modification.

Comment: At the end I used your solution. I think there should be a better way in Terraform, but as today I didn't find one.